# Output CSV has comma after every character in python

Tags: python, csv

Here is my source code

```
import csv
import datetime

csvdate = [datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')]

csvFile = open('test.csv', 'a', newline="")
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
writer.writerow("----------------------------------------------------")
writer.writerow(csvdate)
writer.writerow("Form Action")
writer.writerow("Form URL")
writer.writerow("Suspected Request")
csvFile.close()
```

And the output

```
-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
2020-04-14 10:12:51
F,o,r,m, ,A,c,t,i,o,n
F,o,r,m, ,U,R,L
S,u,s,p,e,c,t,e,d, ,R,e,q,u,e,s,t
```

If it put csv.writerows, all the characters would be in a single column.

Comment: `writerow` takes each item in the sequence and makes it a column in the output file. A string is a sequence of characters, so you get one character per column. What do you want the csv output to look like? I'm not sure what the dash line is for, are the others supposed to be column headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Your code is treating the string as a list

```
writer.writerow(["Form Action"])
writer.writerow(["Form URL"])
writer.writerow(["Suspected Request"])
```

Comment: Or `writer.writerow(["Form Action", "Form URL", "Suspected Request"])` depending on OP's intent.